# Failed to extract manifest

Tags: flutter, dart

I just created a new project on VSCode and got an error when I tried to run it without writing any code. I did `flutter analyze` and `flutter doctor` but no issue was found. The error in Android Studio doesn't apply since am using VSCode. Why is this happening?

What I am seeing in my console:

```
PS C:\Users\NM\Desktop\memo1> flutter analyze
Running "flutter pub get" in memo1... 0.8s
Analyzing memo1...
No issues found! (ran in 7.4s)
PS C:\Users\NM\Desktop\memo1> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on TECNO P904 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done 60.2s
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
CreateProcessW failed 193
Failed to extract manifest from APK: ProcessException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Command: C:\Users\NM\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\aapt.EXE dump xmltree
C:\Users\NM\Desktop\memo1\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml.
Exception: Problem building Android application: see above error(s).
PS C:\Users\NM\Desktop\memo1> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel unknown, 1.20.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1256], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[!] Android Studio
X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Flutter and Dart plugins in Android studio and change flutter channel to `master`